# How to execute mpirun or mpiexec command from a python script?

Tags: python, mpi, client-server, hpc, mpiexec

I have an MPI application written in C++. When I run the application using mpirun or mpiexec on my local machine shell, it works fine. The problem is that the mpi application should be executed after a request from the network (e.g. HTTP request) is received. Assuming that the application server is written in python, how can I execute the mpi application using mpiexec command from a python script? I used `subprocesses.run()` command but nothing happens.

My general question: What is the best way to run an MPI application in client/server architecture?

Thank you

Comment: Insufficient information. `subprocess.Popen("mpiexec -n 4 fooprogramme",shell=True,stdout=stdout)` works for me.

Comment: Thank you. Even when I use ```subprocess.run(["mpiexec"] ,shell=True)``` nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the main python script, MPI should not get imported from `mpi4py` package. Otherwise `subprocess.run("mpiexec")` does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

What options did you use with subprocess.run()? If you are trying to execute a shell command then you need to use shell=True

```
subprocess.run('ls', shell=True)
```

You would replace 'ls' with your mpiexec or mpirun command.

Answer (score 0):

The method that finally worked for me is:

```
import subprocess
```

Define the command like this (separate the keywords):

```
command = ['mpiexec', '-n', '6', 'fooprogramme']
```

Run the command using `subprocess.run` and capture the output to `result`:

```
result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then you can print the output to the console, using:

```
print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Or you can also store `result.stdout.decode('utf-8')`, or write it into a file